# What engine is this?

Tags: engine, diesel

I am considering buying a boat with this Thornycroft diesel engine in it.

- What model is it?
- Any idea where I can find a manual for it?

[image: Engine picture]

Comment: Why not just send [Thornycroft](https://www.thornycroftengines.com/) an email with the image attached and ask them about the engine and if they have a manual for it still. I would bet it is out of production, but they may have both pieces of information for you.

Comment: It almost certainly has a plate attached to it somewhere that gives some basic information about it including its model number.  That would be a good starting point.